# String of Array (not JSON) parsed with eval() - How to secure?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, security, parsing

Im a receiving a string of an array containing objects via http request. I parse it with eval().

So I am clearly expecting an array obj after parsing. How do i secure this eval() procedure, besides of `if (Array.isArray(parsedObj)) ...`

Is there even a better way than eval()?

This is part of the string (note that its not a JSON):

```
    [
        ["2018-06-06", "2018-06-07", "2018-06-08", "2018-06-09", "2018-06-10", "2018-06-11", "2018-06-12", "2018-06-13", "2018-06-14", "2018-06-15", "2018-06-16"], 
        {
            "2018-06-10": {
                checkFirstOrLastOfMonth: 0,
                day: "10",
                dayOfWeek: "SONNTAG",
                formatedDate: "10 Jun 2018",
                monthNo: "06",
                shortMonthName: "Jun",
                weekOfYear: 24,
                year: "2018"
            },
            "2018-06-11": {
                checkFirstOrLastOfMonth: 0,
                day: "11",
                dayOfWeek: "MONTAG",
                formatedDate: "11 Jun 2018",
                monthNo: "06",
                shortMonthName: "Jun",
                weekOfYear: 24,
                year: "2018"
            },
            "2018-06-09": {
                checkFirstOrLastOfMonth: 0,
                day: "09",
                dayOfWeek: "SAMSTAG",
                formatedDate: "09 Jun 2018",
                monthNo: "06",
                shortMonthName: "Jun",
                weekOfYear: 23,
                year: "2018"
            },
    ...
```

Comment: Never use `eval`. Write your own parser then.

Comment: Why don't you make it valid JSON? Fix the HTTP API.

Comment: Checking the type of the outermost expression *after* parsing does not make anything more *secure*.

Comment: @Beri: fixing the API is not in my hand, unfort ...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of eval() use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5

to parse a relaxed JSON like that string into a js obj/arr

```
npm install json5 --save
```

_

```
const JSON5 = require('json5');

let obj = JSON5.parse(obj_str);
```

Comment: JSON5 provides extended set of rules that isn't possible in JSON. E.g. a number can be NaN. Is it desirable? There are multiple packages that parse JSON in more loose manner but don't do any enhancements, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/loose-json